# Reduce a MongoDB id into a shorter hash

Tags: php, hash

I am looking for the best way to convert a MongoDB id `504aaedeff558cb507000004` into a shorter representation in `PHP`? Basically, users can reference id's in the app, and that long string is difficult.

The one caveat is, collisions should be 'rare'. Can we somehow get it down to 4, 5 or 6 characters?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a hash? What about base64-encoding the value?

Comment: Doing base64 on the above id returns: `NTA0YWFlZGVmZjU1OGNiNTA3MDAwMDA0`. Not short.

Comment: What about an array the application level that just maps some key you can make up to the MongoDB id? You could start at 00001 or something, keeping a counter to ensure that you don't have any collisions, and storing array keys in base64 or something so you can cram a bunch of numbers into 5 digits.

Comment: base64 usually lengthens strings. In this specific case, justl ike all lenghtening function issues, you know your character set: 0-16, a-f. What you want to do is to expand this as much as possible. More info and an example in the answer that I'm about to type!

Comment: You can’t go below a maximum of 17 (alphanumeric) characters, down from 24, without losing any information. If you need shorter strings, truncate them (and lose information).

Answer (score 1):

While a hex digit can store 16 different states, a base64 encoded digit can store 64 different states, so you can store your whole MongoDB Id in 16 digits instead of 24 without losing any information:

```
print hexToBase64("50b3701de3de2a2416000000") . "\n"; # -> ULNwHePeKiQWAAAA
print base64ToHex("ULNwHePeKiQWAAAA") . "\n";         # -> 50b3701de3de2a2416000000

function base64ToHex($string) {
  return bin2hex(base64_decode($string));
}

function hexToBase64($string) {
  return base64_encode(hex2bin($string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unique ID to start with can be mapped by `[0-9a-f]`. Shortening can be done in multiple ways - one easy way is to re-map character sets.

Our aim will be to cut the string size in two by replacing characters. A single character is one of 16, so two characters gives you 16^2 = 256 possibilities... I'm sure you know where I'm going with this. Take each couple of characters in your string, and calculate the mapping value. Generate the ASCII character corresponding, and use this instead. If you dislike having such an ugly ID at the end, base64-encode it - you'll get a string which is roughly 1/3 shorter than the one you started with.